# Remove input filed value onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove input filed value while click on button.How can i do that.

For example

```
<input type="text" name="text"> /***************IF value =Akram ************/
<input type="button">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="Akram">
<input type="text" name="text" value="something else">

<input type="submit" value="button" id="btn" />
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == "Akram")
        $(this).val('');
    }); 
});
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/e7j24/5/

Answer (score 4):

You can use an html only solution, when you put your input elements in a form

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <input type="reset" />
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2a73Z/2/)

And here is a Javascript version

```html
<input id="text" type="text" name="text" />
<input id="button" type="button" />
```

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function() {
    text.value = '';
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2a73Z/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    if($('input[type=text]').val() == 'something') 
       $('input[type=text]').val('');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="text" id="input" />
<input type="button" onclick="if($('#input').val() == 'Akram'){ $('#input').val(''); }" />
```

Comment: .input will select by class. You need #input to select by ID

Comment: You have two selectors